# Shell script without shebang = sha256sum or other shasum = error

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh, shebang

I need to do some sha256sum (or shasum -a 256 if sha256sum not installed via homebrew).

But I've a big problem because if I don't have the shebang and don't prefix the script with bash or zsh interpreter, the output isn't good.

Script sha256sum :

```
echo -n 'toto@xyz.tld' | sha256sum
echo -n 'rehiohroie479236893264932fheoi' | sha256sum
echo -n '479823498326598230hgfiejdbgojeklnsfesahofwyr89379832' | sha256sum
echo -n 'w10+_+___!foiefioeoewo' | sha256sum
echo -n '[423].4324234234?5723854' | sha256sum
```

Script shasum -a 256 if sha256sum not available :

```
echo -n 'toto@xyz.tld' | shasum -a 256
echo -n 'rehiohroie479236893264932fheoi' | shasum -a 256
echo -n '479823498326598230hgfiejdbgojeklnsfesahofwyr89379832' | shasum -a 256
echo -n 'w10+_+___!foiefioeoewo' | shasum -a 256
echo -n '[423].4324234234?5723854' | shasum -a 256
```

Output without interpreter prefix (not good) : ./test.sh

```
6cb303b5912a48ac7b9629b7e6b0d0f019f90e3431fbec5e938b3ee51d73c396  -
bfa1f20ad0995f80699b17d2801f6851ae04a84beb0fb0f767970a49d0408157  -
22b1d65df960fe03a33db01529ab417f4936dcd9c2b95f9a010ffb4f1d82a2a5  -
d99e836ce741c053137d72eccbe8c6a96f9f6fa695b14e383673bf3b9872419a  -
c9bdf1c7556abe6763171d9a6a7f407cfbb355f7237bc81a9900f54e0d4f3e37  -
```

Output with interpreter prefix (good) : bash test.sh

```
e908b502b471063233985fa655eab4173178a466079a7e12a93bbfca3ef64d63  -
8d794d4d4f130fced60e52bf83f1fdfb67f8a852bc38f964672cdf62e64b2628  -
5a1efde32fe2ca5b7523c02cef944cb88b98dde8143f9ad7ad07f587502b8566  -
ce4a893b9372d74a78e74f0850308fb5d6b8a9cdba8c230e0ecfe2dbb38f72f7  -
2584ddef1f4b2900c3d1659c59a7cd107523318c686cd64eb1dd5cd8deff0e8b  -
```

If I execute each line of scripts directly, it's the good output.

Can you tell me if I've an error in my setup (zsh profile) or if I need a special env ?

My actual versions: problem reproducible with each version

- From Homebrew :

  ```
  zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)
  GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)
  ```
- Official Apple (macOS Mojave) :

  ```
  zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0)
  GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
  ```

Regards

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Comment: Is your question "why does `echo -n` give different results in different shells?" or is it "how do I reliably output data in a posix shell script?"

Comment: Your "not good" results are what you get if the input starts with "`-n `" and ends with a newline. `echo -n` (or `-e` or...) is hopelessly inconsistent between between versions, so don't use it; use `printf` (e.g. `printf '%s' 'toto@xyz.tld'` instead. See [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/313349/bash-script-echo-n). (Mind you, you should *also* use a shebang.)

Comment: @Cyrus I use bash and sh on servers but on my laptop, I use zsh

Comment: @thatotherguy echo -n is to have a return without \n and my question is a mix of the both you are writing

Comment: @GordonDavisson but using a python3 script, I've no error and for the shebang, sometimes I miss it and thinking that a simple script doesn't need it

Comment: @Cyrus zsh is now the default shell on macOS Catalina : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @GordonDavisson is working as expected by remplacing `echo -n` by `printf '%s'` like :

```
printf '%s' 'toto@xyz.tld' | shasum -a 256
printf '%s' 'rehiohroie479236893264932fheoi' | shasum -a 256
printf '%s' '479823498326598230hgfiejdbgojeklnsfesahofwyr89379832' | shasum -a 256
printf '%s' 'w10+_+___!foiefioeoewo' | shasum -a 256
printf '%s' '[423].4324234234?5723854' | shasum -a 256
```

Now, I need to update my scripts to have a right shebang and/or use printf.
Thanks you